# How to access $and operator from Filter<T> in Typescript, in method where Filter<T> is passed in as a parameter?

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I have some code which works, but keeps on throwing up TypeScript errors in my IDE. I have condensed the code down to show what my issue is.

I have a type (`TestModel`), a method which is used to build a massive query on that model (`generateTestFilter`), and further methods which handle the logic of each filter condition (`handleNameFilter`). When trying to access the `$and` operator within the `handleNameFilter`, TypeScript doesn't like this for some reason, whereas if I try to access it in the method `generateTestFilter`, there are no issues here. Any idea why this happens?

```
import { Filter } from "mongodb"

export interface TestModel {
    name: string,
    things: string[],
    stuff: number
}

function generateTestFilter(tm: TestModel) {
    const filter: Filter<TestModel> = { $and: [] }

    handleNameFilter(tm, filter)

    if (filter.$and && filter.$and.length) { // $and can be accessed here with no issues
        return filter
    }
    return null
}

function handleNameFilter(tm: TestModel, filter: Filter<TestModel>) {
    const condition: Filter<TestModel> = {name: 'Steve'}
    filter.$and.push(condition) // Property '$and' does not exist on type 'Filter<TestModel>'. Property '$and' does not exist on type 'Partial<TestModel>'.ts(2339)

}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMWAGxgUynAvnAMyghDgCIQIA7AcwgBMAjMgKBcwA9JY5gqsoBAIYBjTHAAqmAM4wAsg0xpELOGrhUhITAC44sqHxoAaVepgALI9L0GjAbQC6p9fpgBXAgT1V3IRtgsuGwE7lQiMMDUcDSYVNhCWFKyqBjYABQwIHrJ8opoAJQqriLUsoToAnqpAgA8uQr0SgB8cAC8iHAAJEJU9HpOeGyuFr30aJgAclqYNRlZxhVpUAXD6sAEcOkEldgAdD19cABkx0sCB2N7E7SWRUgA9A-dY3AivXABcKJi0tKY9DgFmw4gA7sBLBoILw-u4ZGZXGooJgPFAqOdAq5gq5kaj0b40GggiEwhEoujRn0JtNtHMoJlspIZHkmmhFjtltVdlB6szGi17gi3mV4KU+hDyVzlrzZPy0K0OghNNo9AByADKWAAbphVdj1ByLod6HswO5pBZ0mL6BLqEUnnAAArEMDYGAATzgquNqrg9AgMih8E4wHK0Q9rq9dJlLJaqr2Tpdbs93rGvv9gaoEGDHFD8HD7sjqsdQlgwCEaBjcua8Zg0nSACYAMxNgCcqyCQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides @Wing detailed explanations, implementing the solution actually requires a bit of both "options":

- As described in point 2, make sure the `$and` operator is *also* initialized within your `handleNameFilter` function (`filter` argument being a `Filter`, it may not have it *yet*)
- We still need a bit of point 1 (i.e. enforcing the existence of `$and` member in parameter), *because* of the union in `Filter`: in case the argument is a plain `Partial<TestModel>`, it does not expect adding later on that `$and` operator, i.e. TypeScript does not like when we "transform" the type to use the other part of the union

```
function handleNameFilter(
    tm: TestModel,
    // Force TS to accept adding later on the $and operator,
    // otherwise it complains because the Partial<TSchema> part of the union
    // does not expect it.
    filter: Filter<TestModel> & { $and?: Filter<TestModel>[] }
) {
    const condition: Filter<TestModel> = { name: 'Steve' }

    // Make sure the $and operator is present and initialized
    filter.$and ??= []

    filter.$and.push(condition) // Okay
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMWAGxgUynAvnAMyghDgCIQIA7AcwgBMAjMgKBcwA9JY5gqsoBAIYBjTHAAqmAM4wAsg0xpELOGrhUhITAC44sqHxoAaVepgALI9L0GjAbQC6p9fpgBXAgT1V3IRtgsuGwE7lQiMMDUcDSYVNhCWFKyqBjYABQwIHrJ8opoAJQqriLUsoToAnqpAgA8uQr0SgB8cAC8iHAAJEJU9HpOeGyuFr30aJgAclqYNRlZxhVpUAXD6sAEcOkEldgAdD19cABkx0sCB2N7E7SWRUgA9A-dY3AivXABcKJi0tKY9DgFmw4gA7sBLBoILw-u4ZGZXGooJgPFAqOdAq5gq5kaj0b40GggiEwhEoujRn0JtNtHMoOkEXAsjkZHkmmgXOonihoGJJABlJnQn6YMDwIT0ehGOBoRLYODRSziQ6AiBgBIwaCctTciBKqDg-68eClcCyvjST6Yd7uI1KuAABSEsGAQjQ9X5ImBICErTAzvgEE29rC5MZ3PoEBkUPgnHVEWNe0ZO2W1V2UHqrMaLROnRVAH408tM7Js2hmoNgvdGaUqOVa1LItQi3UGvlWh0kJptHoAOT8rAAN0wvaG4eeciEAGtxNJ3MimcCXkc1RroDC4GBkf9+N8jnwIa60MAAF4A5Ppy5HfP5jpONZqFMXFV7MC2izpBuH6hFbkAeSnIQAE9iSAA)

Comment: Following on from Wing's explanation, this provides the cleanest solution in my opinion. For anyone that stumbles across this in the future, give Wing's reply a read for a better understanding of why this error happens.

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

The definition for `Filter` looks like this:

```
/** A MongoDB filter can be some portion of the schema or a set of operators @public */
export type Filter<TSchema> =
  | Partial<TSchema>
  | ({
      [Property in Join<NestedPaths<WithId<TSchema>, []>, '.'>]?: Condition<
        PropertyType<WithId<TSchema>, Property>
      >;
    } & RootFilterOperators<WithId<TSchema>>);
```

– [node-mongodb-native/src/mongo_types.ts:67-74 @ 5f37cb6](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/5f37cb6454878294ae004d13a5fcf62eef6adbbe/src/mongo_types.ts#L67-L74)

You can see it's a [**union**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of two types with the following meaning:

1. All the properties on `TSchema` made optional.
2. A mapped type (too long to explain) [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with the root filter operators (of which `$and` is a valid property).

### Why the error in `handleNameFilter`?

As the type is a union, by default, you can only access properties/methods that are valid for every member of the union. In `handleNameFilter` you attempt to access `$and`. This property only appears in the second half of the union but does not appear in the first half (`Partial<TestModel>`). As a result, TypeScript raises an error.

### Why no error in `generateTestFilter`?

Previously, I've written:

> As the type is a union, by default, you can only access properties/methods that are valid for every member of the union.

However you can narrow the type to one side of the union. Narrowing is giving TypeScript information to help make a type more specific (aka narrow). In `generateTestFilter` you've done this here:

```
const filter: Filter<TestModel> = { $and: [] }
```

It's actually not significant that the property name in the object assigned to `filter` is `$and`. What is significant is that the property name is not one that appears in `TestModel`. As none of the properties match the properties of `TestModel`, it doesn't satisfy the first half of the union (`Partial<TestModel>`) so TypeScript narrows it to the second half of the union. You can test this by changing the key/value to match properties in `TestModel` – this should raise the error.

## Solution

Now that the problem has been explained, we should be able to move to a solution. At first glance, it may seem the answer is to somehow narrow the type. However there's an additional problem I'd like to get to, which I think is the actual root cause.

```
function handleNameFilter(tm: TestModel, filter: Filter<TestModel>) {
    const condition: Filter<TestModel> = {name: 'Steve'}
    filter.$and.push(condition) // Property '$and' does not exist on type 'Filter<TestModel>'. Property '$and' does not exist on type 'Partial<TestModel>'.ts(2339)

}
```

Your `handleNameFilter` function takes in an argument at the `filter` parameter that is typed to `Filter<TestModel>` then makes a push to the `$and` property on `filter`. However there's no guarantee that `$and` will exist in the first place. `$and` only exists because of this:

```
    const filter: Filter<TestModel> = { $and: [] }

    handleNameFilter(tm, filter)
```

Hypothetically, in the future, you may refactor this and remove the first line. This will break your logic. TypeScript is protecting you from this.

As a result, you'll somehow need to make `$and` available to push to. The options are either:

1. Enforce the existence of the `$and` property in the type of the `filter` parameter. Although, I would not recommend this because the responsibility of adding the property would be better placed within the function. Therefore:
2. Add the `$and` property to `filter` as part of the logic in your function.

Comment: Amazing explanation, thanks a lot for that! The option 2 you have suggested will not be suitable for me in my use case I believe, as I plan to have further methods to build up the filter (i.e. `handleThingsFilter` & `handleStuffFilter`), and I want all those conditions to live within a single `$and` property.

EDIT - I just re-read it, I initially thought you meant to remove the `$and` from `generateTestFilter` and to have it within the handler functions. I now understand you meant that I should ALSO add it within those functions